# In BW6.7, while testing JDBC connection getting error : java.sql.SQLException: [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver] null

Tags: oracle, jdbc, tibco, tibco-business-works

In BW6.7, while testing JDBC connection I am getting below error. This error is intermittent and earlier it was working fine. Can you please help me with this issue ?

java.sql.SQLException: [tibcosoftwareinc][Oracle JDBC Driver] null

I have place **ojdbc8.jar** at

<<TIBCO_HOME>>\bw\6.7\config\drivers\shells\jdbc.oracle.runtime\runtime\plugins\com.tibco.bw.jdbc.datasourcefactory.oracle\lib

and

<<TIBCO_HOME>>\bw\6.7\config\design\thirdparty

also installed oracle-driver

Comment: The mentioned exception refers to the tibcosoftwareinc driver (DataDirect driver bundled in BusinessWorks 6.X) not the ORACLE native JDBC driver (ojdbc8.jar). You may need to check the code you are testing (check driver and URL format)